# XAMPP - 'The requested URL was not found on this server' error, how can I troubleshoot it?

Tags: apache, installation, xampp, url-routing

I am trying to install a script on XAMPP and I am getting a 'The requested URL was not found on this server' error. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

I rewrote the htaccess file from

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 "You dont have permission to access"
deny from all
```

to

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 "You don't have permission to access this directory."
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

but still nothing happened whats the possible solution

Comment: Hi, please format your code... Well formatted questions are understood faster. Read  [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "The requested URL was not found on this server" is a 404 error.
Is there any interesting entry in apache logfile?
Check if the path and the name of the file are correct.
Also check the root directory in apache and uppercase if on linux system.